# Expected value of mean plus the deviation from the mean

Tags: probability, expected-value

Suppose $r$ and $\theta$ are random variables with:

$r = \bar{r} + \tilde{r}$

$\theta = \bar{\theta} + \tilde{\theta}$

where $\bar{r}, \bar{\theta}$ are the means, and $\tilde{r},\tilde{\theta}$ are the deviations of $r$ and $\theta$ from their mean.

I'm trying to verify the following formula:
\begin{align}
\mathbf{E}(r \cos\theta) &= \mathbf{E}[(\bar{r} + \tilde{r}) \cos(\bar{\theta} + \tilde{\theta})] \\
&= \mathbf{E}[(\bar{r} + \tilde{r})(\cos\bar{\theta}\cos\tilde{\theta} - \sin\bar{\theta}\sin\tilde{\theta})] \\
&= \bar{r} \cos\bar{\theta}
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\mathbf{E}(r \sin\theta) &= \mathbf{E}[(\bar{r} + \tilde{r}) \sin(\bar{\theta} + \tilde{\theta})] \\
&= \mathbf{E}[(\bar{r} + \tilde{r})(\sin\bar{\theta}\cos\tilde{\theta} + \cos\bar{\theta}\sin\tilde{\theta})] \\
&= \bar{r} \sin\bar{\theta} \mathbf{E}[{cos \tilde{\theta}]}
\end{align}

where $\tilde{r}$ and $\tilde{\theta}$ are independent and their probability density functions are symmetric around their means (e.g. Gaussian or uniform).

I really do not understand how to verify these formulas.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Where is $\theta$ supported?

Comment: @rubikscube09 what do you mean by that?

Comment: Can $\theta$ take on all possible real numbers? Or have we restricted it to say $[0,2\pi]$

Comment: But this can't be true.  If $r, \theta$ are constants (i.e. the deviations are both $0$) then $E[r \cos \theta] = r \cos \theta \neq r + \cos \theta$

Comment: @rubikscube09 $r \in\mathbb{R}$ and $\theta \in [0, 2\pi]$

Comment: @antkam sorry, i just edited the equation. I made a typo, that should be $r cos\theta$ not $r + cos\theta$.

Comment: The 1st ingredient you will need is: For any independent r.v. $X, Y, E[XY] = E[X]E[Y]$.  The 2nd ingredient is more subtle...  The deviations have zero means, and coupled with the symmetric distribution this allows you to evaluate $E[\cos \tilde{\theta}]$ and same for $\sin$.  Do you think you can finish from here?

Comment: @antkam how can you verify that $\mathbf{E}[cos \tilde{\theta}] = 1$ is true

Comment: @antkam for example, the textbook says that if $\theta$ is uniformly distributed between $\theta_m$ and $-\theta_m$ then $\mathbf{E}[cos \tilde{\theta}] = \frac{sin \theta_m}{\theta_m}$

Comment: oh my, you are right, I was wrong, and esp. the Answer below is right.  you cannot say $E[\cos \theta] = \cos E[\theta]$ in general.  There might be special cases.  In fact you might need $\cos \bar{\theta} = 0$...?  But not for general $\bar{\theta}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second formula is correct, but the first one is not.

First we do some expansion:

$$E[r \cos \theta] = E[r] E[\cos \theta] = \bar{r} E[ \cos \bar{\theta} \cos \tilde{\theta} - \sin \bar{\theta} \sin \tilde{\theta}] = \bar{r} \cos \bar{\theta} E[\cos \tilde{\theta}] - \bar{r} \sin \bar{\theta} E[\sin \tilde{\theta}] $$

$$E[r \sin \theta] = E[r] E[\sin \theta] = \bar{r} E[ \sin \bar{\theta} \cos \tilde{\theta} + \cos \bar{\theta} \sin \tilde{\theta}] = \bar{r} \sin \bar{\theta} E[\cos \tilde{\theta}] + \bar{r} \cos \bar{\theta} E[\sin \tilde{\theta}] $$

In the above, the first equal sign (of each line) uses the fact that $r$ and $\theta$ are independent.  The other equal signs rely on all the barred quantities being constants.  So finally the question becomes how to evaluate $E[\cos \tilde{\theta}]$ and $E[\sin \tilde{\theta}]$.

By definition, since $\tilde{\theta}$ is the deviation $\theta - \bar{\theta}$, its own mean is $E[\tilde{\theta}] = 0$.  Moreover, it is given that its distribution is symmetric, i.e. $p(\tilde{\theta}) = p(-\tilde{\theta})$ where $p$ is the PDF.  Since $\sin$ is an odd function, i.e. $\sin x = - \sin (-x)$, this means $E[\sin \tilde{\theta}] = 0$.  The gory details follow:

$$E[\sin \tilde{\theta}] = \int^{+\infty}_{-\infty} \sin \tilde{\theta} p(\tilde{\theta}) d\tilde{\theta} = \int^0_{-\infty} \sin \tilde{\theta} p(\tilde{\theta}) d\tilde{\theta} + \int^{+\infty}_0 \sin \tilde{\theta} p(\tilde{\theta}) d\tilde{\theta}$$

Next we show that the two integrals cancel each other:

$$\int^0_{-\infty} \sin \tilde{\theta} p(\tilde{\theta}) d\tilde{\theta} = \int^0_{+\infty} \sin (-\phi) p(-\phi) (-d\phi) = \int^0_{+\infty} (- \sin \phi) p(\phi) (-d\phi)     $$

$$ = \int^0_{+\infty} \sin \phi \ p(\phi) d\phi = - \int^{+\infty}_0 \sin \phi \ p(\phi) d\phi$$

In the above, the first equality is a change of variable $\phi = -\tilde{\theta}$, the second equality uses both $\sin()$ being odd and $p()$ being even (symmetric), and the rest is just algebraic manipulation.

So $E[\sin \tilde{\theta}] = 0$.  Unfortunately, the same cannot be said of $E[\cos \tilde{\theta}]$: it would depend on the exact distribution.  Indeed, I won't repeat it here but you will find that, because $\cos()$ is even, i.e. $\cos x = \cos (-x)$, the $\int^0_{-\infty}$ integral and the $\int^{+\infty}_0$ integral are equal, as opposed to being opposite signs.  So $E[\cos \tilde{\theta}]$ does not equal $0$ in general.  Thus we are left with:

$$E[r \cos \theta] = \bar{r} \cos \bar{\theta} E[\cos \tilde{\theta}] - \bar{r} \sin \bar{\theta} E[\sin \tilde{\theta}] = \bar{r} \cos \bar{\theta} E[\cos \tilde{\theta}]$$

$$E[r \sin \theta] = \bar{r} \sin \bar{\theta} E[\cos \tilde{\theta}] + \bar{r} \cos \bar{\theta} E[\sin \tilde{\theta}] = \bar{r} \sin \bar{\theta} E[\cos \tilde{\theta}] $$

Comment: Thank you for your time antkam

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that the statements are true. Consider the example where r is any symmetric distribution (as in symmetric around the expected value) with $E[r]=1$ and $\theta \sim uniform(-\pi,\pi)$. Then

$$E[\cos(\theta)] = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi \cos(x) dx = 0 $$

however $\cos(E[\theta]) = \cos(0)=1 $, thus $E[r\cos(\theta)]=0 \neq 1 = E[r]\cos(E[\theta]) $.